# nested recycler view IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to reproduce this bug. I open and close the elements of the outer RecyclerView and click on the elements of the inner RecyclerView and IndexOutOfBoundsException error occurs at some point. I think it happenes because I move some code from ViewHolder bind method to ViewHolder constructor.

Exception occurs in Inner Recycler View ServiceViewHolder when I click
This is fragment of code where exception occurs

```
binding.mbExchange.setOnClickListener {
                listener?.onItemClick(items[adapterPosition])
            }
```

Outer recycler view

```
    class GroupAdapter @Inject constructor() : RecyclerView.Adapter<GroupAdapter.GroupViewHolder>() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mDecimalFormat: DecimalFormat

    val items = ArrayList<Pair<Group, List<Service>>>()
    val icons =
        arrayListOf(R.drawable.ic_globe_1, R.drawable.ic_envelope_1, R.drawable.ic_outgoing_call)
    val viewPool = RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool()
    var shouldShowButton = false
    var progress: ObservableBoolean? = null
    var listener: BaseViewHolder.ClickListener<Service>? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GroupViewHolder {
        return GroupViewHolder(
            ViewHolderBCGroupBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GroupViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position], icons[position % icons.size])
    }

    inner class GroupViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private val binding: ViewHolderBeelineClubGroupBinding
        private val adapter: ServiceAdapter
        private val childLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager

        constructor(binding: ViewHolderBCGroupBinding) : super(binding.root) {
            this.binding = binding
            adapter = ServiceAdapter()
            adapter.shouldShowButton = shouldShowButton
            adapter.progress = progress
            adapter.listener = listener
            adapter.mDecimalFormat = mDecimalFormat
            childLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(binding.root.context)
            binding.rvServices.layoutManager = childLayoutManager
            binding.rvServices.adapter = adapter
            binding.rvServices.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool)

            binding.root.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.divider_background)?.let {
                RecyclerViewDivider.with(binding.root.context)
                    .drawable(it)
                    .hideLastDivider()
                    .build()
                    .addTo(binding.rvServices)
            }
        }

        fun bind(item: Pair<Group, List<Service>>, icon: Int) {
            binding.item = item.first
            binding.ivIcon.setImageResource(icon)

            //childLayoutManager.initialPrefetchItemCount = item.second.size
            adapter.items.clear()
            adapter.items.addAll(item.second)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                item.first.isExpanded = !item.first.isExpanded
                notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inner recycler view

```
    class ServiceAdapter @Inject constructor() :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ServiceAdapter.ServiceViewHolder>() {

    val items = ArrayList<Service>()
    var shouldShowButton = false
    var progress: ObservableBoolean? = null
    var listener: BaseViewHolder.ClickListener<Service>? = null
    var mDecimalFormat: DecimalFormat? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ServiceViewHolder {
        return ServiceViewHolder(
            ViewHolderBCServiceBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.context
                ), parent, false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ServiceViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
    }

    inner class ServiceViewHolder : BaseViewHolder<Service> {
        val binding: ViewHolderBeelineClubServiceBinding

        constructor(binding: ViewHolderBCServiceBinding) : super(binding.root) {
            this.binding = binding
            this.binding.progress = progress
            this.binding.mbExchange.visibility = if (shouldShowButton) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            binding.mbExchange.setOnClickListener {
                listener?.onItemClick(items[adapterPosition])
            }
        }

        override fun bind(item: Service) {
            binding.item = item
            binding.tvPrice.text = "${mDecimalFormat?.format(item.price)} Beep"
        }
    }
}
```

stack trace

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.market.adapter.ServiceAdapter$ServiceViewHolder$1.onClick(ServiceAdapter.kt:47)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:967)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Please add where exactly that error occurs (which line of code in which function)

Comment: I updated question and showed place where exception occurs

Comment: I added stack trace to question

Comment: I might miss something, but where is `adapterPosition` ever declared?

Comment: adapterPosition it's RecyclerView method getAdapterPosition

Comment: Try to use position instead of adapterPosition.

Comment: But getPosition deprecated method

Comment: getPosition didn't help

Comment: Maybe it happens because I fill my inner recycler view like this 
            adapter.items.clear()
            adapter.items.addAll(item.second)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I saw some example. In every example they create inner recycler view in ViewHolder on Bind method, but in my case I created inner recycler view in ViewHolder constructor. Maybe it occurs for that reason?